# What is the right thing to do with an unanswered question, which has no significance for me anymore?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, unanswered-questions, accept-rate

I have a question on SO, that is a [real question but is unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559093/why-doesnt-apache2subprocess-spawn-my-subprocess), but it doesn't have any significance to me anymore and though I wouldn't delete it I don't want to have accept rate penalty for it. What is the right thing to do in this case? In particular, if I make it community wiki, will it take accept rate penalty off?

People start whining about my low accept rate on SO and I'm worried if it can affect their will to spend time for answering my questions.

Comment: Why won't you delete it?

Comment: As for the rest of your questions, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: @Shog9 Because I think someone may have the same issue.

Comment: @Shog9 This counts as an answer, thanks!

Comment: @codeholic: if it's not answered, then it doesn't really help them, does it?

Comment: @Shog9 Someone may answer this question later... Though if it is a community wiki, chances are few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question goes unanswered, and you don't find a solution yourself ( outside of linux :D ) and it hasn't gained sufficient attention ( i.e upvotes and comments ) to warrant any more attention, I'd delete it.

Comment: Unless of course its community wiki, then all you can do is flag it for moderation instead of deletion.

Answer (score 1):

If it is of no significance because you solved the issue, you should answer it yourself and accept your own answer.

Comment: But I don't know the answer! :) In this case, is "Move to Linux" a sufficient answer? ;)